# What are the tasteful herbs served with dizi in Iran?

Tags: vegetables, herbs

I’ve tasted Iranian dizi and loved the herbs that where served with it. Leaves look like basil and have a minty taste. Does anyone know what it is?

Thanks :)

[image: a leaf]

Comment: google says that it can mint and tarragon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume it was mint. There are a lot of different variations of mint, from really spicy peppermint down to fruity flavors such as strawberry.

You probably had the Moroccan mint / *Mentha spicata var. crispa*. If you have specialty stores for Mideastern cuisine ask for "Nane"

---

Edit, after your addition of the Picture: By the looks I would suggest [Thai basil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_basil), although this does not really have a minty taste and the stems should be darker ... or [basil mint](https://www.victoriananursery.co.uk/Mint_Plant__Basil_Mint/)

Hard to say as both plants have so many variations to them. If it hat a distinct minty tase, I´d look into one of the mint variations.

---

And additional edit:
Just hat a look on my own herbs, and realized that the young Thai Basil I planted looks exactly like your picture, light greeen stems and all:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Iranian basil. It's got a taste that's distinct from italian or thai basil. I've never gotten basil that tastes quite the same in a US grocery store, but there are a few varieties that taste similar. Apparently you can buy seeds online and grow your own though.

*Sabzi khordan* will also often include mint, tarragon, parsley, chives, spring onions, or radishes as well.